# Java error with the Google Android "HelloFormStuff" tutorial

Tags: android

I am a java neophyte.  I followed the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html to add a button and OnClick handler by copying the tutorial code into mine:

```
public class FormStuff extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.android_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on clicks
                Toast.makeText(FormStuff.this, "Beep Bop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        }
}
```

In Eclipse this produces two errors

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})  FormStuff.java  /FormStuffExample/src/com/example/formstuffexample  line 17 Java Problem
The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int) FormStuff.java  /FormStuffExample/src/com/example/formstuffexample  line 17 Java Problem
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Based purely on the error messages...

You're using the (implicitly) the wrong `OnClickListener` interface/class.  It looks like there are two, View.OnClickListener and DialogInterface.OnClickListener.

The solution is to fully qualify your annonymous OnClickListener.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on clicks
                Toast.makeText(FormStuff.this, "Beep Bop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: +1
One of the drawbacks of letting Eclipse resolve/fix your imports (and you being casual about it) :)

Comment: +1 - Awesome. I had this error working through the tutorial as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kevin. Followed your suggestion I fixed my error too. Eclipse offers too many hints and a newbie like me have no idea what should I choose. Later, I found another solution. If Eclipse cannot import the required when you hit O, you should manual add it:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Comment: Just adding that line fixed the problem for me. Thanks!